# varargs mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to String 1 error

Tags: java

I have the following java program which is not getting compiled:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void funcA (String... params) {
    funcB(params, "a", "b");
  }

  public static void funcB (String... params) {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      funcA("a", "b");
  }

}
```

The compile error is as follows:

```
HelloWorld.java:4: error: method funcB in class HelloWorld cannot be applied to given types;
    funcB(params, "a", "b");
    ^
  required: String[]
  found: String[],String,String
  reason: varargs mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to String
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 709ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that I was slightly misunderstanding the concept of varargs in java. Varargs act just like a Java array. So, when I am calling `funcB(params, "a", "b");`, the signature is actually `(String[], String, String)` whereas earlier, I was assuming it to be `(String...)`.

The confusion arose because params in funcA's parameter is having a signature of `(String...)` and so, when it gets propagated to funcB like `funcB(params, "a", "b");` it would have a signature of `(String..., String, String)` which would mean `(String...)`

The correct program can be written by squishing `params`, `"a"` and `"b"` into another array and then passing that newly created array in funcB; something like below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void funcA (String... params) {
    int paramsLength = params.length;
    String[] finalParams = Arrays.copyOf(params, paramsLength + 2);
    finalParams[paramsLength] = "a";
    finalParams[paramsLength+1] = "b";
    funcB(finalParams);
  }

  public static void funcB (String... params) {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      funcA("a", "b");
  }

}
```

Comment: @mypetlion In SO, there is an option to "Answer your own question" which is available while you are asking a question. The idea is to share the knowledge and help others if you already know the answer rather than just keeping it to yourself.